# Convert PHP's uniqid() to real time with JavaScript(jQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a very short code to perform this in JavaScript(jQuery):

```
date("r",hexdec(substr(uniqid(),0,8)));
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of that code?

Comment: uniqid() is just for storing in mysql avoiding duplicated ID (two users hit "save" on the same millisecond). JS code is for user to see the date and time (accuracy in microseconds not required).

Comment: You also need javascript implementation of `uniqid()` or this data will come from somewhere?

Comment: @Radio: MySQL will not create duplicate id's if the table is configured correctly (e.g. `AUTOINCREMENT`)

Comment: @Radio `uniqid()` is used to generate a unique ID, it doesn't necessarily mean you use it for a database (it's usually not the case), it's usually given to generate a long and random string to identify something, for example, as a ticket ID for a user to follow. Which returns us to the question, what are you trying to achieve in JavaScript? Why do you need such a code?

Comment: No, auto increment + date and time in DATETIME format. That's the proper way.

Comment: +1 for @Truth... let the the DB handle all of this stuff.

Comment: @Radio It's not handling programming stuff (what does that even mean?), it's just a few lines in an SQL script, and it's logically the correct place to do it.

Comment: Storing things in multiple columns in a table is a database's specialty. If you wanted to store all of the data in a single column, there are better ways of doing so (such as CSV for instance). Use auto increment and DATETIME to store both the ID and the timestamp separately, it makes more sense, it's more readable and more maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
var uniqid = '4f36688f15996';

new Date(parseInt(uniqid.substr(0, 8), 16) * 1000);
// Sat Feb 11 2012 14:09:35 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Comment: Hmmm, it returns current time, not the one in var uniqid. =)) http://jsfiddle.net/XzgBf/

Comment: @Radio The `new` keyword was missing. It does work now: http://jsfiddle.net/XzgBf/1/. For the difference between `new Date` and `Date`, see [MDN: Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Description).

Comment: Thank you @Rob for correction. I'm so used to omit `new` keyword for built-in objects like Date, RegExp.. But in this case `new` is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

That seems overcomplicated…

```
php > echo hexdec(substr(uniqid(),0,8)), "\n", time();
1328965876
1328965876
```

You only need a little formatting to convert JavaScript `toString` into what you need.

```
php > echo date('r');
Sat, 11 Feb 2012 14:12:16 +0100

js> new Date().toString();
"Sat Feb 11 2012 14:11:51 GMT+0100 (CET)"
```